# earthing a metal fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have a metal ceiling rose and a metal bulb holder.

The bulb holder is earthed and I'm using three core electrical wire so will be earthing the bulb holder but the metal ceiling rose has a soldered in earth wire,  would that be redundant if the bulb holder is earthed?

Comment: Probably, but with grounding more is usually better than less.  With metal, you want all pieces to be wired/attached to ground.  Usually screws attaching the fixture to the box are used with/out a separate ground wire.

Comment: It would only be redundant if the bulb holder and the rose made electrical contact.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm in the UK, I expect the general principles in this answer to apply most places, but details of rules and practices may differ.

Assuming your are describing a pendant light, normally the rose and the lampholder are seperate items that are not in tight mechanical contact with each other. Depending on the particular design the lampholder may be supported purely by the cord, or their may be chains. These chains do not provide a solid connection suitable for earthing. So if the rose needs to be earthed then it needs to be earthed independently of the lampholder.

Generally metal enclosures containing electrical wiring that is uninsulated or protected by only basic (inner) insulation should be earthed. So if the inner cores of the pendant flex and/or the fixed wiring and/or splicing connectors are exposed inside the ceiling rose (or in a box that functions as part of the same enclosure as the ceiling rose) then it should definitely be earthed. Similarly if the flex (even with it's sheath) can rub against metal parts of the rose then the flex should be earthed.

Arguably if the flex simply passes through the rose fully intact, and the bushing where it passes through the rose is made of plastic then there is no need to earth the rose. Most installers in the UK would probably earth it anyway though.

P.S I have seen some metal fittings that try to claim class 2 "double insulated" status by having secondary insulation and a terminal box. The problem with these fittings is that they may well pass Class 2 requirements when installed exactly as the manufacturer specified, but all too often people's existing wiring is not conducive to doing that. Thus the fittings end up installed in a way that makes them effectively class 0.